# scrollTo always works, smoothScrollTo only sometimes

Tags: android

I've subclassed HorizontalScrollView so that I can have some custom scrolling behavior, but have found that smoothScrollTo doesn't always fire.
I've had to work around this problem by using the following code:

```
smoothScrollTo(x, y);
scrollTo(x, y);
```

This makes sure the scrolling actually gets done even if smoothScrollTo doesn't work, since scrollTo works every time. Why is this happening? How can I get smoothScrollTo to work every time?

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(x, y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You could improve the quality of this answer by explaining what you're doing and why it will help.

Answer (score 1):

**Following code will work:**

```
            final int scrollposition = Math.round(hr/24.0f * 1440f);

            final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.graphScrollView);
            //sv.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollposition);

            sv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sv.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollposition);
                }
            });
```

**Reason:**
It will wait for the scrollview to be posted before running the underlying code.